# Valgrind mysterious invalid write of size 8 error

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

I've searched far and wide and found no answers, so the best option is to ask my own question. I'm currently doing an assignment for university which requires us to build a node that has a key and value string.

I structured the following node, alongside the following two functions:

```c
typedef struct node_t
{
    char *key;
    char *data;
} * Node;

Node nodeCreate()
{
    Node node = NULL;
    node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (node == NULL)
        return NULL;
    node->key = NULL;
    node->data = NULL;
    return node;
}
void nodeDestroy(Node node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    if (node->key != NULL)
        free(node->key);
    if (node->data != NULL)
        free(node->data);
    free(node);
}
```

However, the code above gives me the following error:
[image: Valgrind error message]

Now, this is the plot twist. **If I remove the code for the data, the code works fine and valgrind does not give any issues**.

I can't find any fixes for this, and it's holding me up on a big assignment, and I don't know what to do. **Any** help is appreciated.

Comment: this is because `* Node` in your typedef, *Node* represent a pointer, remove the "*"

Comment: trust on *valgrind* and continue to use it, even when you think a program is out of error

Comment: @bruno I can't edit that, I'm going according to a specific header file I was provided.

Comment: ok, sad, because that was a bad idea to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

The above will only allocate the necessary size to store a pointer to `struct node_t` because of how you defined `Node`.

Either change the line to:

```
node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
```

Or define Node as an alias of `struct node_t` instead of a pointer to it.

Comment: @GeorgeSarji I encourage you to never have `typedef` defining a pointer to, this is the cause of a lot of errors and masking the pointer makes the code difficult to read/understand

Answer (score 3):

```
node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

Is allocating space that is enough for only one pointer.

On the other hand, the structure has 2 pointers, so typically it will be larger than one pointer.

The line should be

```
node = malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));
```

or

```
node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
```

to allocate sufficient space.

Answer (score 0):

in

> ```
> malloc(sizeof(Node))
> ```

you do not allocate a `node_t` as you expected but a pointer to it

replace it by

```
malloc(sizeof(struct node_t))
```

It is a bad idea to define a type pointer, that produces that kind of error, replace

> ```
> typedef struct node_t
> {
>     char *key;
>     char *data;
> } * Node;
> ```

by

```
typedef struct node_t
{
    char *key;
    char *data;
} Node;
```

and do not mask the pointer everywhere

Comment: Both of `sizeof(*Node)` and `sizeof(node_t)` are invalid.

Comment: @MikeCAT yes I missed the 'struct' if this is what you mean

Comment: Yes, for latter half.

Comment: @MikeCAT I didn't see there are already answer, there was absent when I put the remark, better I delete my answer then

Comment: The latter half part of your answer is not on others' answers, so I don't think your answer should be deleted.

Comment: @MikeCAT is it in Julien Thierry answer

Comment: @MikeCAT so UV it ^^